# PHP Array | "Notice: Use of undefined constant.." OR "Notice: Undefined offset: 0.."

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, fetch

im trying to loop through my array, without success though..

Array

```
( 

    [Aircraft] => Array  
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [A] => Gulfstream G100
                    [B] => Cessna Citation Excel
                    [C] => Cessna 208
                    [D] => Piper Aztec
                    [E] => Embraer ERJ 145
                    [F] => Airbus A330
                    [G] => Boeing Business Jet
                )


            [1] => Array

                (
                    [A] => Cessna Citation CJ3 
                    [B] => Dassault Falcon 900
                    [C] => Gulfstream G300
                    [D] => Boeing 767
                    [E] => ATR 42
                    [F] => Gulfstream IV
                    [G] => Airbus A320  
                )
        )
)
```

i have tried almost everything i can think of so far..

even..

```
print $data[0][A];
```

.. wount work.

My plan is to loop (foreach?) through this array..

please help me..

Comment: We need to see some code where you've tried to loop. You should be trying something like `$data['aircraft'][0][A]` surely?

Comment: what do you want as result ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($array['Aircraft'] as $array){
     echo $array['A'];
}
```

Have you tried something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach($array['Aircraft'] as $array){
    echo $array['A']." "; // Will print Gulfstream G100 Cessna Citation CJ3 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: so damn easy.. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Very easy way : use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` functions to dump variable in php
But, for a specific needs, you have to think with recursive approach

```
function loopRecursive($input) {
    foreach ($input as $key => $value ) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            loopRecursive($value);
        }
        else {
            printf('Key: %s value: %s<br /> ',$key, $value);
        }                                  
    }
}
```

Comment: This is over complex for the question.. Leave recursive answers for questions that need a recursive approach

Answer (score -1):

We need to see some code where you've tried to iterate through the array. You should be trying something like `$data['aircraft'][0][A]` to access a single item's value.

Something like this should work to loop through:

```
foreach ($array AS $aircraft) {
    echo $aircraft[A] . PHP_EOL;
}

// Gulfstream G100
// Cessna Citation CJ3
```

Hopefully enough to give you an idea.